# Can't get django urls to work

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I've got a simple django setup in which I have one app called '*lists*'. I now want `http://127.0.0.1:8000/lists` to show this app. So I changed my main urls.py to the following:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^lists/', include('lists.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

and I changed the urls.py which resides in the lists-folder (my app is called lists) to the following:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from lists import views

urlpatterns = patterns(
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index')
)
```

As far as I know I am following the instructions in [the django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/tutorial03/) perfectly well, but when I visit `http://127.0.0.1:8000/lists` (**without** trailing slash) it gives me the following error:

```
Page not found (404) Request Method:    GET Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/lists

Using the URLconf defined in companyLists.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

    ^lists/
    ^admin/

The current URL, lists, didn't match any of these.
```

and when I visit `http://127.0.0.1:8000/lists/` (**with** a trailing slash) it gives me the following error:

```
Page not found (404) Request Method:    GET Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/lists/

Using the URLconf defined in companyLists.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

    ^admin/

The current URL, lists/, didn't match any of these.
```

I don't understand why it doesn't search for ^lists/ anymore when I visit the url with the trailing slash. Does anybody know what I am doing wrong here?

All tips are welcome!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're missing the empty string at the start of your `patterns` in lists `urls.py`.

Try this:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index')
)
```

The blank string is a [view prefix](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urls/#django.conf.urls.patterns) that you can use to assist with the DRY principal. It is used to prefix your views path.

For example, (extending your example above):

Rather than having:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^homepage$', views.homepage, name='index'),
    url(r'^lists$', views.lists, name='index'),
    url(r'^detail$', views.detail, name='index'),
)
```

You can use:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('views',
    url(r'^$', index, name='index'),
    url(r'^homepage$', homepage, name='index'),
    url(r'^lists$', lists, name='index'),
    url(r'^detail$', detail, name='index'),
)
```

To have [multiple view prefixes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#multiple-view-prefixes) just segment your `urlpatterns`.

```
urlpatterns = patterns('views',
    url(r'^$', index, name='index'),
    url(r'^homepage$', homepage, name='index'),
    url(r'^lists$', lists, name='index'),
    url(r'^detail$', detail, name='index'),
)

urlpatterns += patterns('more_views',
    url(r'^extra_page$', extra_page, name='index'),
    url(r'^more_stuff$', something_else, name='index'),
)
```

Comment: Ah, I overlooked that. That indeed works! But most importantly; why? Why does it need an empty string in the beginning?

Comment: updated my answer now @kramer65 - hope that makes it clearer.